# Did my Linear algebra textbook make a mistake here or am I misunderstanding something?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

[image]

So, it is my understanding that bold text indicates a vector. Why are **a**$_1$ **a**$_2$.... **a**$_n$ listed in bold text? Are **a**$_1$ **a**$_2$.... **a**$_n$ not referring to columns which only "consist" of one variable and therefore are not vectors? I thought that each row, not column, of the matrix A was a vector.

plese help me with what i am not understanding, thanks.

Comment: In the matrix $\begin{bmatrix} 1&&0\\0&&1\end{bmatrix}$, columns are $\mathbf e_1=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$ and $\mathbf e_2=\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Please use a more descriptive title and mathjax formatting

Comment: You should re-read the first sentence in your image.

Comment: but I am not understanding how e1 is a vector. We cannot go 1 in the x direction AND 0 in the x direction.

Comment: Whenever anyone shows you a column vector, you either say all the numbers are $x$ coordinates or they are all $y$ coordinates. Why do you keep saying this? Who told you this? Where did you get the idea?

Comment: rolled back your edit, because you deleted the image, which made the question difficult to make sense of

Comment: Here $A$ is written using "block notation". The first column of $A$ is the column vector $a_1$, and so on.

Comment: @DavidK - Because that's how you're first introduced to vectors in high school and they don't go beyond that there. It took me too a loooong time to understand that mathematicians use the word "vector" to mean any "bunch of numbers", and that vectors aren't always arrows in 2D/3D space. You can use them that way, yes, but that's just one use for them. It's like someone took the word "triangle" and started to use it for something other than the geometric figure without first explaining what they mean by it. Anyone would be confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, your confusion arises because you think of the vector $(2,3)$ as going "$2$ units in the $x$ direction and $3$ units in the $y$ direction", so something like $$\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{a}_1&\mathbf{a}_2&\cdots&\mathbf{a}_n\end{bmatrix}$$
confuses you since you cannot go "$\mathbf{a}_1$ units in the direction of the first variable". The problem here is that thinking about vectors as "going a certain distance in a certain direction" only works when the vectors we consider have real components. In general however, the components of a vector can be anything from a complex number to another vector of real entries (they can come from any *vector space*). In this case, we can think of a matrix as a vector of vectors: for instance with
$$\mathbf{a}_1=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix},\mathbf{a}_2=\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix},\mathbf{a}_3=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix},$$
we have
$$\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf a_1&\mathbf a_2&\mathbf a_3\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&1\\0&1&1\end{bmatrix}$$
by simply writing the column vectors down together, concatenating them together in sequence.

Comment: I think "vector of vectors" is confusing here in this context, since it would have to involve thinking of a matrix as a row vector whose entries are column vectors (or vice versa). (though you seem to have helped the OP)

Answer (score 3):

This example should help you understand.

The matrix $\begin{bmatrix} 1&&2\\3&&4\end{bmatrix}$ has columns $\mathbf c_1=\begin{bmatrix}1\\3\end{bmatrix}$ and $\mathbf c_2=\begin{bmatrix}2\\4\end{bmatrix}.$

It could be written $\begin{bmatrix} \mathbf c_1&&\mathbf c_2\end{bmatrix}$.

Indeed, each row of a matrix can be thought of as a vector, and each column can be as well.

Comment: but I dont understand how c1 and c2 are both vectors! 1 and 3 only correspond to x and 2 and 4 only correspond to y.

Comment: As the first sentence of your image indicates, a vector in $\mathbb R^2$ can be denoted $(1,3)$ or $\begin{bmatrix}1\\3\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: I am not understanding how c1 can be thought of as a vector when its components are are constants for the same unknown variable. like we cant move 1 in the x direction AND 3 in the x direction.

Comment: More abstractly, $2$-tuples of real numbers are vectors -- they can be added and multiplied by scalars -- whether they are written $(x,y)$ or $\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: uhg, its hopeless. I am not communicating my question properly.

Comment: in c1. 1 corresponds to x and 3 also corresponds to x, neither correspond to y in any way.

Comment: perhaps you should stop thinking in terms of $x$ and $y$ and instead think in terms of 1st component and 2nd component, and the vector could be written as a row with the 2nd component to the right of the 1st component or as a column with the 2nd component beneath the 1st component

Answer (score 0):

"There are two commonly used ways to denote the $n$-tuples of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. As rows [...] or columns".

If your vectors are rows, then each row of your matrix $A$ is a vector. If your vectors are columns, then each column of your matrix $A$ is a vector.

In the matrix you give:
$$A= \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{a}_{1} & \mathbf{a}_{2} & \cdots & \mathbf{a}_{n} \end{bmatrix}$$
each $\mathbf{a}_{i}$ represents a **column vector**, and represents a column of the matrix $A$.

You could just as easily use $\mathbf{r}_{1}$, $\ldots$, $\mathbf{r}_{m}$ to represent row vectors, and write
$$A = \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{r}_{1}\\ \mathbf{r}_{2} \\ \vdots \\\mathbf{r}_{m} \end{bmatrix}$$ where each $\mathbf{r}_{j}$ represents a row of the matrix $A$.